# How to use the Homebrew's Ruby package instead of the Ruby package that comes with MacOS?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

How can I switch from using the version of Ruby that comes with MacOS to the most recent version of Ruby that I downloaded using Homebrew?

My version of MacOS appears to have `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]` already installed with the system at `usr/bin/ruby`. I tried running `brew install ruby` to get the most recent version of Ruby however when I run `ruby -v` the same old version shows up. I figured I probably had to add it to my path so I went to my `~/.bash_profile` and added

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin/ruby:$PATH"
```

but still `ruby -v` shows the old version. I closed the terminal, reopened the terminal, ran `source ~/.bash_profile` with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out my mistake.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin/ruby:$PATH"
```

Should have been

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin:$PATH"
```

then just run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and confirm with `ruby -v` or `type -a ruby`

Answer (score 2):

@prettycoder's answer almost did it for me. I needed to do an `rbenv init` as well to get the proper version of ruby when running `ruby -v`:

```
brew install rbenv
brew upgrade ruby-build
rbenv install 2.6.5
rbenv global 2.6.5
 or
rbenv local 2.6.5
rbenv init
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a version manager, e.g. `rbenv`

```
 brew install rbenv
 brew upgrade ruby-build
 rbenv install 2.6.1
 rbenv global 2.6.1
 or
 rbenv local 2.6.1
```

Details about rbenv here: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: Thanks, surely I don't need `rbenv` to do this though?

Comment: @Robby using a ruby version manager like rbenv should help setup your paths correctly, both for ruby AND (importantly) for installing gems via `gem install` and `bundle install`. Plus, it's easier to switch/upgrade versions later

Comment: After doing this - `ruby -v` still points to the version preinstalled with Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin:$PATH"
```

It is better to use this

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

Which is a symbolic link of `../Cellar/ruby/2.6.1`. You can use `readlink` to print it.

Then you don't need to worry about upgrading ruby.

Answer (score 0):

For M1 / apple silicon users:

As per the official ruby formula caveat as of version 3.2.2.1:

```
If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

^ can adapt to whatever shell you're using.
This fixed the issue for me and my ruby went from `/usr/bin/ruby` to `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`, which was the correct version.