# Unable to change Ruby path from macOS package to Homebrew package (running macOS Monterey with Intel Core i7)

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, homebrew, rbenv

**Summary of issue and current configuration**

I have installed the latest versions of `rbenv` and `ruby-build` via Homebrew on macOS Monterey (currently running version 12.6.5 with Intel Core i7 chip), however every time I check the latest Ruby version with `ruby -v`, I receive the following:

```
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]
```

Whenever I run `which ruby`, I get the following back:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I checked both my `.zsh_profile` and `.zshrc` files within my home directory and don't see any paths that indicate that Ruby/Rbenv are set to that specific path.

`zsh_profile`

```
# Add NVM
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
    [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && source "$file";
done;
unset file;

# Case-insensitive globbing (used in pathname expansion)
shopt -s nocaseglob;

# Append to the Bash history file, rather than overwriting it
shopt -s histappend;

# Autocorrect typos in path names when using `cd`
shopt -s cdspell;

# Enable some Bash 4 features when possible:
# * `autocd`, e.g. `**/qux` will enter `./foo/bar/baz/qux`
# * Recursive globbing, e.g. `echo **/*.txt`
for option in autocd globstar; do
    shopt -s "$option" 2> /dev/null;
done;

# Add tab completion for many Bash commands
if which brew &> /dev/null && [ -r "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]; then
    # Ensure existing Homebrew v1 completions continue to work
    export BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR="$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d";
    source "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh";
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    source /etc/bash_completion;
fi;

# Enable tab completion for `g` by marking it as an alias for `git`
if type _git &> /dev/null; then
    complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g;
fi;

# Add tab completion for SSH hostnames based on ~/.ssh/config, ignoring wildcards
[ -e "$HOME/.ssh/config" ] && complete -o "default" -o "nospace" -W "$(grep "^Host" ~/.ssh/config | grep -v "[?*]" | cut -d " " -f2- | tr ' ' '\n')" scp sftp ssh;

# Add tab completion for `defaults read|write NSGlobalDomain`
# You could just use `-g` instead, but I like being explicit
complete -W "NSGlobalDomain" defaults;

# Add `killall` tab completion for common apps
complete -o "nospace" -W "Contacts Calendar Dock Finder Mail Safari iTunes SystemUIServer Terminal Twitter" killall;test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
test -f ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
test -f ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
test -f ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc

if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then
    . ~/.zshrc
fi
```

`.zshrc`

```
# Git
function parse_git_branch {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "("${ref#refs/heads/}")"
}
export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$(parse_git_branch)\n$ "
export EDITOR='atom --wait'
export VISUAL='atom --wait'


  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  . $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE

# Add `~/bin` to the `$PATH`
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

# Rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
   eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

**Steps taken so far to resolve the issue**

After browsing a few similar threads, it appears that the problem here is that macOS is defaulting to its own Ruby package and not the latest package that was installed from Homebrew. Here are the steps I have taken so far to attempt to fix this issue, to no avail:

- uninstalled `rbenv` and `ruby-build` by running `brew unlink ruby-build`, `brew uninstall rbenv`, and `brew uninstall ruby-build`
- reinstalled `rbenv` and `ruby-build` by running `brew install ruby-build`, `brew install rbenv`, and `brew link ruby-build`
- install latest ruby version via rbenv by running `rbenv install '3.2.2'` and `rbenv global '3.2.2'`
- set Ruby path and source in `.zshrc` file by running `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
- run `brew update` and `brew upgrade`, which didn't throw any errors
- run `brew doctor`, which also didn't throw any errors

I've also browsed these following threads, but each of the solutions within those threads (most of which were listed in the steps above) have unfortunately not fixed the problem for me so far:

- [How to use the Homebrew's Ruby package instead of the Ruby package that comes with MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471291/how-to-use-the-homebrews-ruby-package-instead-of-the-ruby-package-that-comes-wi)
- [Why won't rbenv or chruby switch to an installed version of Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75881076/why-wont-rbenv-or-chruby-switch-to-an-installed-version-of-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Update 5/12/2023:

After further researching documentation on bash to zsh for macOS Catalina (and later), it turns out that my the default path that my terminal was configured to was `/bin/bash`, which I had subsequently configured to `/bin/zsh`.

Additionally, I ran the following shell commands:

```
if [[ $SHELL != '/bin/zsh' ]]; then
  echo "shell was $SHELL" 
  echo 'changing shell to zsh...'
  chsh -s /bin/zsh "$(whoami)"
fi
```

And now, here is the following ruby version I get back:

```
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin21]
```

And the new path:

```
$HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```